# i am using Google map API in my webpage. i need to specify my place using my image how to do this?

Tags: asp.net, api

i am using Google map API in my webpage. i need to specify my place using my own image. how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Custom Icons](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Custom_Icons).